# Weird behaviour with xsl:text and double &#xa; and text()/identity template

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I want to convert the following `xml` input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<doc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <title>title</title>
    <foo>x</foo>
</doc>
```

Into this output

```
\section{title}

x
```

I tried this `xsl` sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="title">
        <xsl:text>\section{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>}&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="foo">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output had trailing spaces and was indented, like that:

```
    \section{title}

    x
```

Now after some search, I found that if I muted `template` on `text()`, I could get somewhat what I wanted. I replaced the identity template with the following:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="self::text()"/>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

When applied to the `xml` input, it gave me that:

```
\section{title}
x
```

So apparently the new line `&#xa;` disappeared. What I understand even less, if that I modify the stylesheet, adding another `&#xa;`, to that:

```
<xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:text>\section{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>}&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

to

```
 <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:text>\section{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>}&#xd;&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

then there is a new line in the output where I want it. As if my stylesheet was eating one new line exactly.

I don't understand what's going on, could someone tell me:

1. How do I obtain the desired output?
2. What's happening with the `&#xa;&#xa;`?

My processor is saxon 9.7 if that's relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note instruction `<xsl:text>}&#xd;&#xa;</xsl:text>` in your code.

It actually does not print any **double** newline, but a pair of
**CR**/**LF** chars, corresponding to a **single** newline in Windows.

One more detail: the **CR** character is not needed here because,
even using an XSLT processor under Windows it is enough to output just
the **LF** char (`&#xa;`).

So to get a **really double** newline (and preceding `}`, write
`<xsl:text>}&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>`.

Another instruction you should add is `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`.
For details/explanation search the Web.

As far as `xsl:output` instruction is concerned, in `text` mode the `indent`
attribute doesn't matter, you can delete it.

And the last issue: Neither the template matching `\` nor the *identity template*
are needer here. Just delete them, the script will be shorter.

So the final (reworked) content of your script, giving your desired output, is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="title">
    <xsl:text>\section{</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:text>}&#xa;&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Okay, thanks I just realized what `newline` meant, I feel silly now.

However, this is a MWE specifically for the newline problem. The real file requires the identity template.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use an identity pattern when you're not trying to produce a document that's nearly identical to your input.

Just have a root template that calls templates to apply to the elements that are relevant to you, thus making the transformation ignore everything that isn't relevant:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/title"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/doc/foo"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <!-- blah blah -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="foo">
  <!-- blah blah -->
</xsl:template>
```

> When applied to the xml input, it gave me that:

```
\section{title}
x
```

> So apparently the new line 
>  disappeared.

Really? Yet it looks to me like "\section{title}" and "x" are not on the same line, which is the same as saying that a new line was inserted between the two.

It sounds like what you want is even more spaces between them than just going to a new line. In other words, you want more new lines than just the one you first obtained. In this case, then yes, it makes sense to add yet another new line, so that the output contains yet another new line.

Also note, that `&#xd;` is a carriage return, the control character often used in pair with the simple new line caracter, `&#xa;`, as going for a new line is usually done by having both a carriage return then a new line character in Windows and text network protocol conventions.

However, in modern times and if what you're producing is LaTeX, the carriage return is unnecessary. You can just stop to have it, and handle having new lines by just having single new line characters.